# Getting top value in px - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason when using JQuery to append a div into a webpage and using, as default; a percentage of 50% on a div for the top. When using JQuery to get the `top` value I get `157.6px`?  In reality it should be somewhere around `400px`.

I am not to sure as to why this is?  Any insight would be much appreciated!

JQuery:

```
...code
//get last x and y cordinates
    if(fontActive == 1)
    {
        var x = $("#draggable").css('left');
        var y =$("#draggable").css('top');
    }
    // default remove old
    $(".customize-Container #draggable").remove();
    //get values
    var text = $("#fontEnter").val();
    var current = $(".activeText a div").attr('id');
    //create a canvas for image converting
    $(".customize-Container").append("<div id='draggable'><canvas id='"+current+"'></canvas></div>");
    //get x and y cordinates if fontActive not 1
    if(fontActive != 1)
    {
        var x = $("#draggable").css('left');
        var y =$("#draggable").css('top');
    }
...code
```

Notice in the above, on first start up `fontActive = 0` where as once this has already been ran, the value of `fontActive = 1.`

Also like I said the `#draggable` has css styles and the `top` value is defaulted to 50%;

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because the `.css('top')` is returning the `top value as relative to the closest parent element with a position defined`. To get the value you want, it's most likely `$('#draggable').position().top +'px'` where you'll have to append the `px` value because it will return an integer. I could be wrong, however, wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Have you set dimensions of any images it may contain? This has caused me issues in the past.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy could you specify example? evolutionxbox I am not because the canvas is what text is rendered into by a image.

Comment: What "Ohgodwhy" is saying is use the `position` function instead.

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to just replace `$('#draggable').css('top')` with the code I supplied, than for me to make a mockup jsFiddle illustrating the theoretical design of your markup.

Comment: Oh sorry @ohgodwhy did not notice that.  It worked :)  put answer and I will mark it!  Blessings, thanks both you guys for your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because the `.css('top')` is `returning the top value as relative to the closest parent element with a position defined`.

To get the value you want, it's most likely

```
$('#draggable').position().top +'px'
```

where you'll have to append the px value because it will return an integer.